# Jenkins Parameterized pipeline always builds master branch

Tags: git, maven, github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parameterized (declarative) pipeline in Jenkins. The script is supposed to build the branch that is passed as parameter but always ends up building the master branch.

This is the snippet from the pipeline script that checks the pom version after building a repo on a specified branch

```
pipeline {
agent any

tools {
    maven "localMaven"
    git "Default"
}

parameters {
    string(defaultValue: 'develop', description: 'Commit/Branch', name: 'prop1')
}

stages {
    stage('Pom-Version') {
        steps{
            echo "prop1 $prop1"

            checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', 
                      userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/path/to/repo', 
                                           credentialsId: 'xxx',
                                           branches: [name: "${params.prop1}"]]]
                    ])

            script {
                pom = readMavenPom file: 'pom.xml'
                modelversion = pom.version.substring(0, pom.version.lastIndexOf("-"))
            }
            sh "echo {$pom.version}"
            sh "echo {$modelversion}"
        }
    }
  .....
```

I set the parameter `prop1=refs/heads/TestBranch`.
The `echo {$pom.version}` shows `1.1.0-RELEASE`. This is the correct release of the master branch. But I am expectecing `1.1.1-SNAPSHOT` for the branch `TestBranch` that I am actually trying to build. 
The log confirms that it is building the master branch instead of TestBranch. Look for the line: `refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit}` in the below log

```
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/https://github.com/path/to/repo # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/https://github.com/path/to/repo
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/https://github.com/path/to/repo +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 9832b614717ebf86f93d983342787b717dcfb4d9 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
Commit message: "Merge branch 'release/1.1.0-RELEASE'"
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 9832b614717ebf86f93d983342787b717dcfb4d9
 > git rev-list 9832b614717ebf86f93d983342787b717dcfb4d9 # timeout=10
```

It should have said `refs/remotes/origin/origin/TestBranch^{commit}` or so.

I am aware that on the jenkins UI in the pipeline config I can set the branches to be built. But this is already set to the repo + branch where the pipeline script should be pulled from. There is likely to occur ambiguity when I configure all the repos there on the UI. I need to achieve this through the pipeline script.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're specifying the branch in the wrong spot in the `checkout` step, since the [userRemoteConfigs class](https://github.com/jenkinsci/git-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/git/UserRemoteConfig.java) doesn't have a `branches` field. It should be something like this:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM',
         branches: [[name: "${params.prop1}"]],
         userRemoteConfigs: [[url: 'https://github.com/path/to/repo', 
                              credentialsId: 'xxx']]
         ])
```